# How javascript knows about the current locale in Rails 3?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, url, internationalization, locale

I'm trying to get a **resouce** from my autocomplete.js.coffee(.erb) file. The resource's URL is dependent on the current locale. That is,

> /en/ajax/posts

or

> /he/ajax/posts

Please note the /en/.

The problem is, I cannot determine the locale from within the .js file.

- Rails Guides does not provide enough info
- i18n-js gem isn't working for me, i.e. I18n.locale gives me null

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved with:

```
def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || session[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
    session[:locale] = I18n.locale  # store locale to session
end
```

It should be noted that the "standard" implementation is:

```
def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
end
```

If you have a better answer, please suggest.